# What is the easiest way to connect two computers?

Tags: usb, connection, connection-sharing

Would a USB -> USB cable work for this??

Comment: What are you trying to do once you connect the two computers?

Comment: USB specific: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195765/is-usb-to-usb-data-transfer-between-two-linux-oses-possible

Comment: See also: [Is there some way to connect two computers using USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/863/is-there-some-way-to-connect-two-computers-using-usb)

Answer (score 10):

The easiest options are (in rough order of practicality):

- connect both devices to the same hub/switch/router via Ethernet - easiest option if you have Internet via ADSL or cable, then you usually already have a switch/router
- connect both devices to the same WLAN network (similar to first option, just wireless instead of wired)
- cross-over ethernet connection (may need a special "cross-over" cable, modern systems will do this automatically)
- USB-to-USB connection; this requires a special cable however, as pointed out by Moab, and special software

Desperate options:

- Parallel-to-parallel (aka LapLink) cable
- serial-to-serial (aka nullmodem) cable

Both are very slow, and have little software support on modern OSes (though they can be made to work, at least under Linux)

In practice, I'd always advise to use option 1 (connect both devices to a router/switch), unless this is totally impractical. That gives you a standard network connection, which is what most software expects.

Comment: Firewire-to-Firewire is also an option (at least on Macs, but since DarkLightA didn't specify his systems...)

Comment: I'd put a direct Ethernet connection at #2 right underneath hooking them to the same switch.  Auto-MDIX is part of the GigE spec -- no cross-over cables required.  However, if one (or both) systems is only 10/100, then a cross-over cable works best.

Comment: @Daniel - Windows XP can also do IP-over-Firewire, but I've never tried hooking 2 systems together via Firewire to see what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need a special usb cable and software like this one

http://www.cablestogo.com/product.asp?cat_id=1504&sku=39977

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would. But if you connected them via an ad-hoc WiFi network, there might be more things that you can accomplish like file sharing / media streaming etc.